# Can I retrieve a phone number from contacts without opening an intent?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to get the phonenumber of a contact programmatically by asking only the name, without display my contacts activity.

Is it possible? and how?

I tried the following but I get a permission error even if I have my permission setup in manifest

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);



    ArrayList<String> contact_names = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cur.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = "GIAGIA";
            if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER.trim())).equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                if (name!=null){
                    //contact_names[i]=name;

                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext())
                    {
                        String PhoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),PhoneNumber ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //i++;
                        break;
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                    pCur.deactivate();
                    // i++;
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Does not exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        cur.close();
        cur.deactivate();
    }

    String[] contactList = new String[contact_names.size()];

    for(int j = 0; j < contact_names.size(); j++){
        contactList[j] = contact_names.get(j);
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

Comment: please post the error you're getting, also, `asking only the name` - you mean asking the user for the contact name? what if there are two contacts by the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean to do is get a contact name from the user and find a phone number in the `Contacts` DB, this should work:

```
public List<String> getPhoneNumbersByName(String name) {
    List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{ name }, null);
    while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
        phones.add = cur.getString(1);
    }
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
    return phones;
}
```

Notes:

1. There can be more then one contact with the same name, this will return all numbers belonging to all contacts matching the given name
2. There can be multiple numbers stored for each contact, so this function returns a list of phones
3. The name must be an exact match, you can relax this limitation by changing the selection to be case-insensitive and/or use `Sqlite`'s "`LIKE`" option